# Problems running built PyTables on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pytables

I built numpy 1.5.1, numexpr 1.4.2, and PyTables 2.2.1 on a Mac, and am getting the following error. I googled it, but found only 1 place where someone mentions this specific error, and found no resolution.

Does anyone know what this means?

Thanks,
Dave

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.5.1'
>>> numpy.__file__
'/Applications/.../__init__.pyc' (i.e., where I put it)
>>> import tables
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 6 but this version of numpy is 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/VORPAL/VORPAL/Python/Extras/lib/python/tables/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tables.utilsExtension import getPyTablesVersion, getHDF5Version
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was able to solve my problem by blowing everything away and making a clean build. So I'm not exactly sure what the problem was, but I think I must have been mixing up versions somehow.